# Programmatic navigation with NavigationView/NavigationLink delay jumps back

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I created [a simple showcase](https://github.com/haemi/NavigationProblem) where my problem can be reproduced; what I'm doing is navigating from the initial view => View1 => View2.

The navigation from the initial to View1 happens via button tap, nothing special here.

My View1 looks the following:

```
struct View1: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    private let includeDelay = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: View2(),
            isActive: $viewModel.foo,
            label: {
                Text("View 1")
            })
            .onAppear(perform: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(includeDelay ? 500 : 0)) {
                    viewModel.doSomething()
                }
            })
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foo = false
    func doSomething() {
        foo = true
    }
}
```

If I include the delay in `onAppear`, it works as expected; after the delay, I get navigated to `View2` and stay there.

But if I remove the delay (or set it to e.g. 300ms) I get navigated to `View2`, but immediately get navigated back. I don't understand what's happening here; why is my `$viewModel.foo` set to false after my setting to `true`?